# 403 Forbidden for Jquery.min.js when developing on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, localhost

I've looked all over google and the site and none of the solutions I've tried have worked... maybe my problem requires something a little more specific.

When I have this site hosted on a test site, it works fine, but I'm getting this error when I use "Inspect Element" on Chrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden). I can tell the jquery file isn't being accessed properly by my site because the jquery that works perfectly on my Go Daddy test site (a cool little tool called Tablesorter) isn't working anymore.

The jquery.min.js file is in a directory called js. Here's the entirety of the head in my html file.

```
<head>
<title>Corporate Dude, Data Management</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1.9"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#data_table").tablesorter(); 
        } 
    );
</script>
</head>
```

The weird thing is that when I move the style.css file into the js directory and change the path to js/style.css, the css works just fine. Does this mean it's not a permissions issue or is it just a peculiarity of the way href works in the link tag?

I've tried going to the terminal and typing cd /Users/myusername/mylocalhostfile/"Corporate Guy"/js then typing chmod 0755 to give permission to access the directory, but that didn't work either. Is this the proper way to assign permissions through the terminal?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Sounds like a `.htaccess` problem.

Comment: There's an .htaccess file in my localhost folder?

Comment: You're accessing your folder through a webserver. "403 Forbidden" is an HTTP error.

Comment: The address I type in my browser to access the site that's creating the error is http://localhost/~myusername/Corporate%20Guy/index.php. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that confirms what I said. The scheme is defaulting to `http:`, so that's short for `http://localhost/~myusername/Corporate%20Guy/index.php`

Comment: You need to go through a webserver to execute PHP scripts. If you access it directly using the `file:` scheme, you'll just load the script source.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. That's why I set up my apache server in the first place; because most of the files I develop are .php files with some kind of function or form processing. Any idea how I fix the issue?

Comment: It might be something in `httpd.conf` restricting access to `.js` files. webmasters.stackexchange.com or superusers.com might be better places to ask about configuring Apache.

Comment: You should also `chmod` the files you want to access. You can check permissions by doing an `ls -l` in the directory where the files exist. Then again, this is probably not the place to discuss this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: accessing jquery locally would not work but accessing it remotely from "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" would work. The problem is that when I downloaded jquery it was stored without reading access to everyone (as json_parse... has below):

```
-rw-r----- 1 jorge jorge  94840 ago  6 04:07 jquery-1.7.2.min.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 jorge jorge   9866 jun 25 06:18 json_parse_20091204.js
```

I changed it thus: `chmod +r jquery-1.7.2.min.js`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jorge jorge  94840 ago  6 04:07 jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check file permissions; it should have read access. I was facing the same issue with AngularJS lib; When I was trying to access it from locally running apache2 server, I was getting:
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

The file had not read permissions:

> -rw-r----- 1 root root 147059 Aug 29 20:20 angular.min.js

Added read-permissions by running:

```
sudo chmod +r angular.min.js
```

And now it's working fine.